# How to include Socket io in external js file linked to html file?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, socket.io

I am using node js, socket io, and express to create a multiplayer web game.
When the server start I listen on port 2000.
When I go to `localhost:2000`, the file `lobby.html` is sent using

```
//app.js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const serv = require('http').Server(app);
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/Client/lobby.html');
});
serv.listen(2000);
var io = require(socket.io)(serv, {});
```

I would include the js for the lobby.html file inside the html file instead of using `<script src='lobby.js>`.

I would also import socket io and the `app.js` file which is the server file in the lobby.html file.
It looked like this:

```
<script src='https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.4.5.js'></script>
<script src='../app.js'></script>
```

Since the js was written in the html file and socket io was included on that html page I could use `var socket = io();` in my js so I can communicate with the server(app.js).

However, I want the js that was written in `lobby.html` to be moved to a file called `lobby.js` using `<script src='lobby.js'>` in the html file and also by using `require(./lobby.js)` in app.js. When I try to do `var socket = io()` in the `lobby.js` file, I get an error saying `io()` is not defined since the js file is separate from the html file.

How can I get socket io to work in the `lobby.js` file.

Incase you need the file structure, here it is:

```
-Game Folder
    -Client
        -lobby.html
        -lobby.js
    -app.js
    -package.json
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply add another route in your express code:

```js
//app.js

// root route
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/Client/lobby.html');
});

// add this
app.get('/app.js', function(req, res) {
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/javascript');
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/Client/app.js');
});
```

and then add the script tag in your HTML:

```html
<script src='/app.js'></script>
```

Remember that every page represents more than one request to the server. Every CSS file, javascript file, image adds another request that the server needs to know how to handle.